# Why does php return an empty Generator if function contains both return and yield?

Tags: php, generator, typeerror, yield, type-hinting

```
// Returns empty generator as expected.
function yieldOnly(): Generator
{
    yield;
}

// Throws TypeError as expected.
function returnOnly(): Generator
{
    return;
}

// Returns empty generator???
function returnAndYield(): Generator
{
    return;
    yield;
}
```

The return value of `returnAndYield()` is an empty `Generator`, although I was expecting it to throw a `TypeError`. Is this the expected behavior? I could not find it documented anywhere and am wondering if this is potentially a bug that should be reported.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual about the [generator syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php) says the following:

> Any function containing `yield` is a generator function.

So by having the `yield` keyword in there results in having a generator function. With the `return` keyword you are quitting the function, which is used to build a generator function. In this case it's just empty because before the `return` statement are no `yield` lines. When you use the following source code:

```
function returnAndYield(): Generator
{
    yield 1;
    yield 2;
    return;
    yield 3;
    yield 4;
}

$result = returnAndYield();
echo implode(',', iterator_to_array($result));
```

you will get the following output:

```
1,2
```

The values `3` and `4` are not in the generator because the function exits before these `yield` statements.